# Fastapi - Copy data with sqlalchamy to couchbase

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, couchbase, fastapi, pydantic

Webserver - fastapi

the sqlahcmay ORM model name--> CustomerModel,
where the pydantic schema --> SchemaCustomerBase

The document being fetch correctly see line :

```
customer = get_customer(db, customer_no=customer_no)
```

so all good by ORM side ,
the thing is i want to copy it to couchbase ,
the type of "customer" object is:

```
print(type(customer))
<class 'mig.schema.CustomerModel'>
```

the return of "customer" done by response_model=SchemaCustomerBase,
Which indeed return it as valid Json so document is valid json.

I tried several way to convert customer as Json (i.e json.dumps(customer) )
so i could copy it couchbase but it didn't work.

code:

```
def get_customer(db: Session, customer_no: int):
    return db.query(CustomerModel).filter(CustomerModel.customer_no == customer_no).first()


@mig_router.post("/cb_customer/{customer_no}",response_model=SchemaCustomerBase)
def move_customer(customer_no: int , db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    customer = get_customer(db, customer_no=customer_no)
    bucket: Bucket = cluster.bucket("customer")
    try:
       key = customer["customer_type"] + "_" + str(customer["customer_no"])
#here it failed
       result = bucket.upsert(key, customer)
       print(result.cas)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
    
    return customer
```

error:

```
'CustomerModel' object is not subscriptable
```

I missing something here ,
I know i can encode to json but I could use the pydantic model as happend in respone_modle (as it actually work),
how can i use also before injecting the document to couchbase?

Answer (score 1):

solution:

In case u have sqlalchamy and u need to use the pydantic model,
u should add to the pydantic class:

```
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

And in code:

```
    customer_db = get_customer(db, customer_no=customer_no)
    customer_orm = SchemaCustomerBase.from_orm(customer)
```